runuser: execute commands without use of quotation marks?
Overview
I'm attempting to execute commands as a different user without using quotation marks as well as making sure the executed command isn't inheriting environment from the parent shell.
runuser looks like the perfect candidate for this job as it's going to be executed by a privileged user (in a unattended script), there's no setuid bit, has login/PAM session support and it's a part of widely used util-linux package.
Problem
Edit: to clarify further:

The culprit here is that I'd like to switch between multiple users within the same script and execute the commands as they are written from the perspective of the user executing them. Currently variables like $USER or even ~/ gets expanded to the values from parent shell which breaks the entire setup. For a long time I've been using Bash's -c but this requires quotation marks which makes commands with e.g. regex difficult to read.

Original question:

The goal is to display directory listening of user's home (meaning ~/ should translate to /home/build) as the build user (where's a "polluted" shell would return /root). Quotation marks should not be used (to avoid having to escape those with more advanced commands).

The following approach almost works but it unfortunately inherits environment from parent's session:
$ whoami
root

$ runuser --user build -- ls -a ~/
ls: cannot open directory '/root/': Permission denied

Another alternative which I've tried is to create a login session but due to the nature of Bash, the arguments aren't parsed as command_string but instead as a script:
$ runuser --login build -- ls -a ~/
/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

Logically this is usually solved by supplying the -c argument to Bash but this bring us back to square one, it requires quotation marks:
$ runuser --login build -- -c 'set -x; ls -a ~/'
+ ls -a /home/build/

Invoking a separate script fulfills all the requirements but I found this approach to be cumbersome to work with:
# run.sh
whoami
ls -a ~/

$ chown build run.sh
$ chmod +x run.sh
$ runuser build ./test.sh 
+ whoami
build
+ ls -a /home/build/

Question
Are there any other approaches which allows you to avoid quotation marks when executing commands as a different user in a clean environment?

Update 1
Heredoc is the closest solution which fits all criteria but I'm happy to hear if there's more!
# run.sh
runuser --user build -- bash << EOF
set -x
ls -d ~/
whoami
EOF

# Result
+ ls -d /home/build/
/home/build/
+ whoami
build

Update 2
Exporting functions to subshells is also viable and preserves syntax highligh
function CMD {
  set -x
  echo $USER
  ls -d ~/
}
runuser --login build -- -c "$(declare -f CMD); CMD"


The simple answer is runuser --user build -- ls -a ~build/

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' The goal was just an example to demonstrate the context (just updated OP to avoid confusion). The executed commands need their own session/environment which isn't polluted by parent's shell for future proofing :)

There's a misunderstanding here. The problem demonstrated in the question is related to tilde expansion, which is done by the shell you're typing these commands into before actually executing anything. When you run runuser --user build -- ls -a ~/, the actual command that is executed is runuser --user build -- ls -a /root, and those are the arguments that runuser gets. That has nothing to do with whether the "environment" or "session" or whatever that you think the command is being executed in is "polluted" by something.

Thanks for clarifying that @muru! This makes sense but I fail to see the solution (without re-writing the commands)  :/

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' gave the solution, and unless you have some evidence that has a polluted environment, I don't see what the problem with it is.

@muru The culprit is that I'd like to switch between multiple users within the same script and execute the commands as they are written from the perspective of the user executing them. Currently variables like $USER or even ~/ gets expanded to the values from parent shell which breaks the entire setup. For a long time I've been using Bash's -c but this requires quotation marks which makes commands with e.g. regex difficult to read. Hope this makes sense!

If you use a programming language (any of the common ones, Python, Ruby, Perl, whatever), then you can have those switch users using their equivalent of setuid(2) and then subsequent code will be executed as the new user. But the shell doesn't really have an equivalent. Commands like sudo or runuser start a new process and can't affect the calling script itself. You can always try setting $USER and $HOME (which is what's used for tilde expansion) yourself, however.

Single quotes are there to stop the local shell parsing the command. Taking them out would be unsafe

This fulfills ALL requirements:

Allows sandboxed code to be read as it is.
Allows complex quotation of commands executed by runuser without escaping quotes.
Execution is done via a different user (without setuid bit) in an isolated environment (meaning variables aren't inherited from parent shell, unless you explicitly import some which is demonstrated with VARIABLES=())
Tilde expansion like ~/ or $USER is correctly set to invoking user.
Bonus: PAM/login support.
Bonus: runtime level in set -x is set correctly (++).
Bonus: passes shellcheck.
Bonus: imported environment variables are sanitized through serialization to avoid situation where nested variables get incorrectly parsed or possibility of quotation breaking Bash's -c format.

Solution was accomplished by exporting functions, usage of optional arguments in bash -c and a couple of clever syntax tricks (see comments in code):

Bash: If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string. If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Code:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Persistent variables
declare -g VARIABLES=( "import=works" "env=var" )
declare -g EXAMPLE="WONTBEIMPORTED"

# Isolated commands to be executed in a clean environment
function SANDBOX_RUN {
  echo "${USER}"               # = build
  whoami                       # = build
  ls -d ~/                     # = /home/build/
  echo IMPORTED: "${import:-}" # = IMPORTED: works
  echo EXAMPLE: "${EXAMPLE:-}" # = EXAMPLE:
  echo 'quotation' "works"     # = quotation works
}

# Global verbosity
function MAIN_DEBUG {
  set -x
}

# Main logic <----
function MAIN_RUN {
  local ENV=("$(declare -p VARIABLES);" $'[[ -n "${VARIABLES:-}" ]] && declare -g "${VARIABLES[@]}"') # Import variables to subprocess through serialized list
  local CMD=("$(declare -f "${@}");" "{ ${*/%/;} }")                                                  # Import functions by printing escaped contents

  # Treat each Bash argument as a command through eval and parameter expansion whilst RUNNER is the cosmetic name of the caller ($0)
  exec runuser --login build --shell /usr/bin/bash -- -c $'eval "${@/%/;}"' RUNNER "${ENV[*]}" "${CMD[*]}"
}

# What to run
function MAIN {
  MAIN_DEBUG                      # Enable Bash debugging
  MAIN_RUN MAIN_DEBUG SANDBOX_RUN # Execute functions inside sandbox
}

MAIN

Revisions: https://gist.github.com/GrabbenD/01803465f4c2413bf7103caa15dc6791
Hope this spares someone from hours of research :)

what in the world is with all the downvotes? I upvoted all I could for what it is worth. Thank you. I'll give it a try next time I need it, which might be soon.

What you've done here is to quote the values that you said in your question were to be left unquoted. Oh, and added loads of complexity

@ChrisDavies I understand your concern. Quotation and advanced Bash syntax in MAIN functions (what I'd like to call "orchestrator logic") definitely adds complexity at hindsight. However, this is extremely powerful when used in a specialized setup (e.g. if you forward isolated raw functions to different namespaces like chroot/containers/qemu/ssh or just as a different user). The idea is to abstract away orchestrator logic from self encapsulated functions which are re-usable in any environment. Some of the logic like importing VARIABLES might be overly elaborate for simpler use cases.

For clarity, code nested inside SANDBOX_RUN can freely use any quotation since there's zero need to escape it (as it's automatically sanitized by the the orchestrator logic) and the environment from invoking parent shell doesn't spill over into it. Reusable encapsulated functions was my goal, yours might be different :) . If you ever find a different approach, feel free to share it here!

I would use:
/usr/sbin/runuser -l ${dynamicuser} -c 

The -l makes it inherit what it normally would as that user (the user environment) so $USER and ~ should be interpreted as intended.
You might run into similar ugliness with the command -c 'cmds here', but you can just create a script that accepts user;cmd and then your cmd won't look as ugly.
I believe I've had the same gripe and just added a small script to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin named runwithenv and set it executable. Then sudo or as root run the runwithenv with the args, user;cmds-to-be-run.
Or perhaps, since you would then have 2 scripts just write a function called runwithenv:
function runwithenv {
  dynamicuser=$1;
  cmds=$2 # or some such depending on your needs
  /usr/sbin/runuser -l ${dynamicuser} -c "${cmds}"
} 

Then just call the function repeatedly with different users:
runwithenv dynamicuser1 cmds

Might want to add a trap or test to the function and echo results so you can program for it.

Thanks for taking a look Mike. I know this works since I made a mini demonstration of this concept when I made this question but it's not the solution I'm looking for here. Ideally I'd like to keep all the logic within one script and avoid cross pollination of environments. Tough one.

@GrabbenD. My apologies I didn't see "runuser -l" and thought perhaps that was what was missing.  And wait! So, the function didn't work?  I thought surely it would work. And then it would be all in one script. I admit I have not tried the function because I didn't care if it was in 2 scripts. Just the whole escape quotes thing was getting to me.

Yes it works Mike but I'm looking for something different. In other words, I'd like to keep the scope of the logic to one portable script (and limiting this to standardized libraries from widely used packages like util-linux).

But the function would be inside of the one script (at the top). Larger scripts are usually made of many functions right? So it would still be one portable file.

Oh and I have made use of the heredoc, but I always have to look it up..  if you did it in a function and then write the rest of the script, I think that would work.  I will do it myself the next time I need this, which may be soon.

Aw, I missed the new details in your updated answer! Yeah, functions makes it cleaner for sure but I could not find a way of avoiding quotation when invoking the function containing runuser from the main scope :/

I was guessing the HEREDOC would work (though it is ugly in itself) and would only be used inside the function?   I would work on it now, but I have to go. If you figure it out, please post it so I can use it. lol

The Heredoc example from above actually works wonderfully. I'll keep posting more solutions if I find any

This took me a couple of days but I've managed to come up with a really robust solution which I've posted above! Figured you might be interested :)
